# How to iterate thru dynamic number of columns present in xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've an XML that comes from the DB with dynamic number of columns and rows.I need to iterate thru the columns dynamically and construct the table with these columns and rows.

Note: I want to use the same stylesheet for other 2-3 reports where number of columns varies with report to report and do not want to hardcode the column names.Below is my generated XML. Can anyone please help me out iterating thru the columns and rows dynamically in xslt?

```
  <ReportData>
  <Columns>
  <Column>Name</Column>
  <Column>UserName</Column>
  <Column>Remarks</Column>
  <Column>IP Address</Column>
  <Column>Date Created</Column>
  <Column>APP ID</Column>
  <Column>App Version</Column>
  <Column>Last Loggedin</Column>
  </Columns>
  <Rows>
  <Row>
  <Cell>123</Cell>
  <Cell>0.0.0.0</Cell>
  <Cell>2016-02-24T18:32:11.803</Cell>
  <Cell>AOS</Cell>
  <Cell>0.0.3.0</Cell>
  <Cell>2016-05-30T15:25:05.880</Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
  <Cell>123</Cell>
  <Cell>0.0.0.0</Cell>
  <Cell>2016-02-25T10:22:34.623</Cell>
  <Cell>BOS</Cell>
  <Cell>0.0.3.0</Cell>
  <Cell>2016-05-30T15:25:05.880</Cell>
  </Row>
  </Rows>
  </ReportData>
```

Thanks..

Comment: What is the expected ouput?

Comment: "*do not want to hardcode the column names*" The column names are not hard-coded in the input. Why is this a problem? IOW, what have you tried and where are you stuck with this?

Comment: In the XML sample, there are 8 `Column` elements, but each row only has 6 `Cell` elements. Is there any logic to this, or is the XML in the question not fully representative? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C, No logic, It seems i've missed out 2 rows.. Thanks..